# Determining validity of an argument

Tags: logic

I would like to know whether the following argument is valid.

Some amphibians live in the water
All fish live in the water
Therefore, some fish are amphibians.

Comment: it isn't valid. Is any animal in the water a fish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) are sometimes helpful in seeing what’s going on. The conclusion *Some fish are amphibians* would fit this diagram:

[image]

However, the hypothesis fit this diagram just as well, and it describes a world in which **no** fish are amphibians:

[image]

Since the second diagram is consistent with the hypotheses and contradicts the conclusion, the argument cannot be valid.

Answer (score 1):

This argument is not valid.  Notice that some violins make sounds and all pianos make sounds, but this does not mean that some pianos are violins.

The argument is essentially

$\exists x ( \operatorname{Amphibian} (x) \land \operatorname{Water} (x) )$

$\forall x ( \operatorname{Fish} (x) \implies \operatorname{Water} (x) )$

$\therefore \exists x ( \operatorname{Fish} (x) \land \operatorname{Amphibian} (x) )$

The argument would be valid IF the second statement were changed to:

$\forall x ( \operatorname{Water} (x) \implies \operatorname{Fish} (x) )$  (All things that live in water are fish)

In its current form, the argument is an example of affirming the consequent.

Comment: how do i show it.

Comment: Try to think with sets. It helps.